# Code inserting into database twice

Tags: java, javascript, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I have the form

```
<aui:form action="<%= editURL %>" method="POST" name="fm">
    <aui:fieldset>

        <aui:input name="name" />

        <aui:input name="url" />

        <aui:input name="address" />

    </aui:fieldset>

    <aui:button-row>
        <aui:button type="submit" />

        <aui:button name="cancel" value="Cancel"/>

    </aui:button-row>
</aui:form>
```

and this piece of javascript code which is inserting into database twice I don't know why.

```
<aui:script use="aui-base,aui-form-validator,aui-io-request">
    AUI().use('aui-base','aui-form-validator',function(A){
        var rules = {
            <portlet:namespace/>name: {
                required: true
            },

            <portlet:namespace/>url: {
                url: true
            },

            <portlet:namespace/>address: {
                required: true
            },
        };

        var fieldStrings = {
            <portlet:namespace/>name: {
                required: 'The Name field is required.'
            },

            <portlet:namespace/>address: {
                required: 'The Address field is required.'
            },
        };
        alert("validator");
        new A.FormValidator({
            boundingBox: '#<portlet:namespace/>fm',
            fieldStrings: fieldStrings,
            rules: rules,
            showAllMessages:true,
            on: {
                    validateField: function(event) {
                     },
                    validField: function(event) {
                   },
                    errorField: function(event) {
                    },
                    submitError: function(event) {
                        alert("submitError");
                        event.preventDefault(); //prevent form submit
                    },
                    submit: function(event) {
                        alert("Submit");

                        var A = AUI();
                        var url = '<%=editURL.toString()%>';

                        A.io.request(
                            url,
                            {
                                method: 'POST',
                                form: {id: '<portlet:namespace/>fm'},
                                on: {
                                    success: function() {
                                        alert("inside success");// not getting this alert.
                                        Liferay.Util.getOpener().refreshPortlet();
                                        Liferay.Util.getOpener().closePopup('popupId');                                     
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        );
                   }
                }
        });
    });

</aui:script>
```

However if I add the following piece of code, which is redundant because it is already present inside the `submit block` of above code and is not triggered any way because I do not have any `save` button in the form, then the value is inserted only once.

```
<aui:script use="aui-base,aui-io-request">
    A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>save').on('click', function(event) {
        var A = AUI();
        var url = '<%=editURL.toString()%>';

        A.io.request(
            url,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                form: {id: '<portlet:namespace/>fm'},
                on: {
                    success: function() {
                        Liferay.Util.getOpener().refreshPortlet();
                        Liferay.Util.getOpener().closePopup('popupId');
                    }
                }
            }
        );

    });
</aui:script>
```

This code generates `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null` which I think is because there is no `save` button in the form. But adding this code, the value is inserted into database just once which is what I want but the logic is flawed. How can I get the results I want by just by using the first piece of code?

Comment: Given that you get double entry when using the IO request, consider the placement. You've called an IO on an URL within a listener that is actively processing a form submit against the same URL. However, I'd expect the success alert to trigger in that case. Either prevent the default submit or remove the IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insertion was happening twice. Once from the `default form submit` and other from the `A.io.request`. Adding this piece of code

```
<aui:script use="aui-base,aui-io-request">
    A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>save').on('click', function(event) {
        var A = AUI();
        var url = '<%=editURL.toString()%>';

        A.io.request(
            url,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                form: {id: '<portlet:namespace/>fm'},
                on: {
                    success: function() {
                        Liferay.Util.getOpener().refreshPortlet();
                        Liferay.Util.getOpener().closePopup('popupId');
                    }
                }
            }
        );

    });
</aui:script>
```

resulted in the insertion only once. This code has obviously no relevance because there is no `save` button in the form. Hence there was `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null` which masked the flaw and prevented the form from being submitted twice.

Removing the above piece of code and preventing the default submit (by adding `onSubmit="event.preventDefault();` in the form tag) resolves the issue.